# Counting Records with Unique Field Value

Tags: sql, ms-access

### Source Table

Assuming I have a table called `MyTable` with the content:

```
+----------+------+
| Category | Code |
+----------+------+
|    A     | A123 |
|    A     | B123 |
|    A     | C123 |
|    B     | A123 |
|    B     | B123 |
|    B     | D123 |
|    C     | A123 |
|    C     | E123 |
|    C     | F123 |
+----------+------+
```

I'm trying to count the number of `Code` values which are unique to each category.

---

### Desired Result

For the above example, the result would be:

```
+----------+-------------+
| Category | UniqueCodes |
+----------+-------------+
|    A     |           1 |
|    B     |           1 |
|    C     |           2 |
+----------+-------------+
```

Since `C123` is unique to `A`, `D123` is unique to `B`, and `E123` & `F123` are unique to `C`.

---

### What I've Tried

I'm able to obtain the result for a single category (e.g. `C`) using a query such as:

```
SELECT COUNT(a.Code) AS UniqueCodes
FROM 
    (
        SELECT MyTable.Code
        FROM MyTable
        WHERE MyTable.Category = "C"
    ) a
    LEFT JOIN
    (
        SELECT MyTable.Code
        FROM MyTable
        WHERE MyTable.Category <> "C"
    ) b
    ON a.Code = b.Code
WHERE b.Code IS NULL
```

However, whilst I can hard-code a query for each category, I cannot seem to construct a single query to calculate this for every possible `Category` value.

Here is what I've tried:

```
SELECT c.Category, 
    (
        SELECT COUNT(a.Code) 
        FROM 
            (
                SELECT MyTable.Code 
                FROM MyTable 
                WHERE MyTable.Category = c.Category
            ) a 
            LEFT JOIN
            (
                SELECT MyTable.Code
                FROM MyTable
                WHERE MyTable.Category <> c.Category
            ) b 
            ON a.Code = b.Code 
        WHERE b.Code IS NULL
    ) AS UniqueCodes
FROM
    (
        SELECT MyTable.Category
        FROM MyTable
        GROUP BY MyTable.Category
    ) c
```

Though, the `c.Category` is not defined within the scope of the nested `SELECT` query.

Could anyone advise how I could obtain the desired result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use `NOT EXISTS` & do aggregation :

```
select category, count(*)
from MyTable t
where not exists (select 1 from MyTable t1 where t1.code = t.code and t1.category <> t.category)
group by category;
```

Comment: Superb. I was looking at the problem in reverse: iterating by `Category` rather than by `Code` and checking whether each `Code` exists in any other `Category`. Your method is much better. And using `SELECT 1` to improve performance is also a nice touch.

Answer (score 1):

You can use two levels of aggregation:

```
select minc as category, count(*)
from (select code, min(category) as minc, max(category) as maxc
      from t
      group by code
     ) as c
where minc = maxc
group by minc;
```

Comment: Interesting method of selecting the `codes` belonging to a single `category` to enable you to pass the `category` value through to the outermost query and avoid having to re-link the main table - thank you Gordon  for your contribution!

Answer (score 0):

This would also work:

```
select category, count(*) from(
    select a.category,  b.count from mytable a join (
        select code, count(category) as count 
        from mytable 
        group by code 
        having count(category) = 1
    ) b on b.code = a.code
) c group by category
```

Comment: Many thanks for your answer - I had to change `join` to `inner join` since MS Access does not recognise the `join` operator on its own. On reviewing your code, I think `b.count` and `count(category) as count` are not required.

Comment: you are right about the `b.count` I am not sure how I can remove the `count(category)`  though. Anyways, thanx for your response.

Comment: Not all instances of `count(category)`, just changing the line `select code, count(category) as count` to `select code` since the `count(category)` field is always `1` in the result and does not need to be output.

Comment: That is incorrect. I am counting here how many categories each code has. Then I am using the `having count(category) = 1` to get only those that have 1 category.

Comment: Yes, but you can still use the `having count(category) = 1` clause without outputting the `count(category)` field in the `select` statement.

Comment: I've added another answer to hopefully demonstrate what I meant with my comments - thank you for providing the inspiration!

Comment: I agree. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Learning from @isaace's answer, I also came up with this -

```
SELECT MyTable.Category, COUNT(*)
FROM 
    MyTable INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT Code FROM MyTable GROUP BY Code HAVING COUNT(Category) = 1) a 
    ON MyTable.Code = a.Code
GROUP BY MyTable.Category
```